# How to Style the RootNode of a TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a Simple TreeView that looks like this

```
LOCATION 1
       - set1
       - set2
       - set3
LOCATION 2 
       - set1
       - set2
```

Now I'd like to Style the LOCATION(s) -root nodes - in the treeView. How can I do this? My Xaml looks like this.

```
<Support:ExtendedTreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}"               
         SelectedItem_="{Binding SelectedTreeViewItem, Mode=TwoWay}"

    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllSets}" >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="10"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>

</Support:ExtendedTreeView>
```

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124644/Basic-Understanding-of-Tree-View-in-WPF

Comment: @Ash Thanks. I found what I was looking for all the way at the bottom of the article

Comment: nice. the article is long but helpful (i have it bookmarked). you can write a self-answer and accept it :)